# Eclipse Arduino Linker trouble

Tags: eclipse, arduino, avr

I have been trying to get my Arduino/Eclipse environment setup. For some reason I keep having trouble with the linker.

Here is the error I receive when trying to build.
So there is a conflict between libgcc and libc?

I have followed these instructions pretty close, but there are some nuances.

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project CustomLEDPoi ****

make all 
Building target: CustomLEDPoi.elf
Invoking: AVR C++ Linker
avr-gcc -Wl,-Map,CustomLEDPoi.map,--cref -Wl,--gc-sections -L"C:\Users\Justin\workspaceArduino\arduino_core\328P_16MHz Arduino" -L"C:\Users\Justin\workspaceArduino\arduino_core\328P_16MHz Arduino\src" -Xlinker -verbose -mmcu=atmega328p -o "CustomLEDPoi.elf"  ./src/glowstick2.o  ./lib/CShiftPWM.o ./lib/MeetAndroid.o ./lib/hsv2rgb.o  ./arduinolib/HardwareSerial.o ./arduinolib/SPI.o   -lArduinoCore
GNU ld (WinAVR 20081205) 2.19
  Supported emulations:
   avr2
   avr1
   avr25
   avr3
   avr31
   avr35
   avr4
   avr5
   avr51
   avr6
   avrxmega1
   avrxmega2
   avrxmega3
   avrxmega4
   avrxmega5
   avrxmega6
   avrxmega7
cannot find script file ldscripts/avr5.x
opened script file c:\users\justin\arduino\arduino-1.0\hardware\tools\avr\avr\bin\../lib\ldscripts/avr5.x
using external linker script:
==================================================
/* Default linker script, for normal executables */
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-avr","elf32-avr","elf32-avr")
OUTPUT_ARCH(avr:5)
MEMORY
{
  text      (rx)   : ORIGIN = 0, LENGTH = 128K
  data      (rw!x) : ORIGIN = 0x800060, LENGTH = 0xffa0
  eeprom    (rw!x) : ORIGIN = 0x810000, LENGTH = 64K
  fuse      (rw!x) : ORIGIN = 0x820000, LENGTH = 1K
  lock      (rw!x) : ORIGIN = 0x830000, LENGTH = 1K
  signature (rw!x) : ORIGIN = 0x840000, LENGTH = 1K
}
SECTIONS
{
  /* Read-only sections, merged into text segment: */
  .hash          : { *(.hash)       }
  .dynsym        : { *(.dynsym)     }
  .dynstr        : { *(.dynstr)     }
  .gnu.version   : { *(.gnu.version)    }
  .gnu.version_d   : { *(.gnu.version_d)    }
  .gnu.version_r   : { *(.gnu.version_r)    }
  .rel.init      : { *(.rel.init)       }
  .rela.init     : { *(.rela.init)  }
  .rel.text      :
    {
      *(.rel.text)
      *(.rel.text.*)
      *(.rel.gnu.linkonce.t*)
    }
  .rela.text     :
    {
      *(.rela.text)
      *(.rela.text.*)
      *(.rela.gnu.linkonce.t*)
    }
  .rel.fini      : { *(.rel.fini)       }
  .rela.fini     : { *(.rela.fini)  }
  .rel.rodata    :
    {
      *(.rel.rodata)
      *(.rel.rodata.*)
      *(.rel.gnu.linkonce.r*)
    }
  .rela.rodata   :
    {
      *(.rela.rodata)
      *(.rela.rodata.*)
      *(.rela.gnu.linkonce.r*)
    }
  .rel.data      :
    {
      *(.rel.data)
      *(.rel.data.*)
      *(.rel.gnu.linkonce.d*)
    }
  .rela.data     :
    {
      *(.rela.data)
      *(.rela.data.*)
      *(.rela.gnu.linkonce.d*)
    }
  .rel.ctors     : { *(.rel.ctors)  }
  .rela.ctors    : { *(.rela.ctors) }
  .rel.dtors     : { *(.rel.dtors)  }
  .rela.dtors    : { *(.rela.dtors) }
  .rel.got       : { *(.rel.got)        }
  .rela.got      : { *(.rela.got)       }
  .rel.bss       : { *(.rel.bss)        }
  .rela.bss      : { *(.rela.bss)       }
  .rel.plt       : { *(.rel.plt)        }
  .rela.plt      : { *(.rela.plt)       }
  /* Internal text space or external memory.  */
  .text   :
  {
    *(.vectors)
    KEEP(*(.vectors))
    /* For data that needs to reside in the lower 64k of progmem.  */
    *(.progmem.gcc*)
    *(.progmem*)
    . = ALIGN(2);
     __trampolines_start = . ;
    /* The jump trampolines for the 16-bit limited relocs will reside here.  */
    *(.trampolines)
    *(.trampolines*)
     __trampolines_end = . ;
    /* For future tablejump instruction arrays for 3 byte pc devices.
       We don't relax jump/call instructions within these sections.  */
    *(.jumptables)
    *(.jumptables*)
    /* For code that needs to reside in the lower 128k progmem.  */
    *(.lowtext)
    *(.lowtext*)
     __ctors_start = . ;
     *(.ctors)
     __ctors_end = . ;
     __dtors_start = . ;
     *(.dtors)
     __dtors_end = . ;
    KEEP(SORT(*)(.ctors))
    KEEP(SORT(*)(.dtors))
    /* From this point on, we don't bother about wether the insns are
       below or above the 16 bits boundary.  */
    *(.init0)  /* Start here after reset.  */
    KEEP (*(.init0))
    *(.init1)
    KEEP (*(.init1))
    *(.init2)  /* Clear __zero_reg__, set up stack pointer.  */
    KEEP (*(.init2))
    *(.init3)
    KEEP (*(.init3))
    *(.init4)  /* Initialize data and BSS.  */
    KEEP (*(.init4))
    *(.init5)
    KEEP (*(.init5))
    *(.init6)  /* C++ constructors.  */
    KEEP (*(.init6))
    *(.init7)
    KEEP (*(.init7))
    *(.init8)
    KEEP (*(.init8))
    *(.init9)  /* Call main().  */
    KEEP (*(.init9))
    *(.text)
    . = ALIGN(2);
    *(.text.*)
    . = ALIGN(2);
    *(.fini9)  /* _exit() starts here.  */
    KEEP (*(.fini9))
    *(.fini8)
    KEEP (*(.fini8))
    *(.fini7)
    KEEP (*(.fini7))
    *(.fini6)  /* C++ destructors.  */
    KEEP (*(.fini6))
    *(.fini5)
    KEEP (*(.fini5))
    *(.fini4)
    KEEP (*(.fini4))
    *(.fini3)
    KEEP (*(.fini3))
    *(.fini2)
    KEEP (*(.fini2))
    *(.fini1)
    KEEP (*(.fini1))
    *(.fini0)  /* Infinite loop after program termination.  */
    KEEP (*(.fini0))
     _etext = . ;
  }  > text
  .data   : AT (ADDR (.text) + SIZEOF (.text))
  {
     PROVIDE (__data_start = .) ;
    *(.data)
    *(.data*)
    *(.rodata)  /* We need to include .rodata here if gcc is used */
    *(.rodata*) /* with -fdata-sections.  */
    *(.gnu.linkonce.d*)
    . = ALIGN(2);
     _edata = . ;
     PROVIDE (__data_end = .) ;
  }  > data
  .bss   : AT (ADDR (.bss))
  {
     PROVIDE (__bss_start = .) ;
    *(.bss)
    *(.bss*)
    *(COMMON)
     PROVIDE (__bss_end = .) ;
  }  > data
   __data_load_start = LOADADDR(.data);
   __data_load_end = __data_load_start + SIZEOF(.data);
  /* Global data not cleared after reset.  */
  .noinit  :
  {
     PROVIDE (__noinit_start = .) ;
    *(.noinit*)
     PROVIDE (__noinit_end = .) ;
     _end = . ;
     PROVIDE (__heap_start = .) ;
  }  > data
  .eeprom  :
  {
    *(.eeprom*)
     __eeprom_end = . ;
  }  > eeprom
  .fuse  :
  {
    KEEP(*(.fuse))
    KEEP(*(.lfuse))
    KEEP(*(.hfuse))
    KEEP(*(.efuse))
  }  > fuse
  .lock  :
  {
    KEEP(*(.lock*))
  }  > lock
  .signature  :
  {
    KEEP(*(.signature*))
  }  > signature
  /* Stabs debugging sections.  */
  .stab 0 : { *(.stab) }
  .stabstr 0 : { *(.stabstr) }
  .stab.excl 0 : { *(.stab.excl) }
  .stab.exclstr 0 : { *(.stab.exclstr) }
  .stab.index 0 : { *(.stab.index) }
  .stab.indexstr 0 : { *(.stab.indexstr) }
  .comment 0 : { *(.comment) }
  /* DWARF debug sections.
     Symbols in the DWARF debugging sections are relative to the beginning
     of the section so we begin them at 0.  */
  /* DWARF 1 */
  .debug          0 : { *(.debug) }
  .line           0 : { *(.line) }
  /* GNU DWARF 1 extensions */
  .debug_srcinfo  0 : { *(.debug_srcinfo) }
  .debug_sfnames  0 : { *(.debug_sfnames) }
  /* DWARF 1.1 and DWARF 2 */
  .debug_aranges  0 : { *(.debug_aranges) }
  .debug_pubnames 0 : { *(.debug_pubnames) }
  /* DWARF 2 */
  .debug_info     0 : { *(.debug_info) *(.gnu.linkonce.wi.*) }
  .debug_abbrev   0 : { *(.debug_abbrev) }
  .debug_line     0 : { *(.debug_line) }
  .debug_frame    0 : { *(.debug_frame) }
  .debug_str      0 : { *(.debug_str) }
  .debug_loc      0 : { *(.debug_loc) }
  .debug_macinfo  0 : { *(.debug_macinfo) }
}

==================================================
attempt to open c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/../../../../avr/lib/avr5/crtm328p.o succeeded
c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/../../../../avr/lib/avr5/crtm328p.o
attempt to open ./src/glowstick2.o succeeded
./src/glowstick2.o
attempt to open ./lib/CShiftPWM.o succeeded
./lib/CShiftPWM.o
attempt to open ./lib/MeetAndroid.o succeeded
./lib/MeetAndroid.o
attempt to open ./lib/hsv2rgb.o succeeded
./lib/hsv2rgb.o
attempt to open ./arduinolib/HardwareSerial.o succeeded
./arduinolib/HardwareSerial.o
attempt to open ./arduinolib/SPI.o succeeded
./arduinolib/SPI.o
attempt to open C:\Users\Justin\workspaceArduino\arduino_core\328P_16MHz Arduino/libArduinoCore.so failed
attempt to open C:\Users\Justin\workspaceArduino\arduino_core\328P_16MHz Arduino\libArduinoCore.a failed
attempt to open C:\Users\Justin\workspaceArduino\arduino_core\328P_16MHz Arduino\src/libArduinoCore.so failed
attempt to open C:\Users\Justin\workspaceArduino\arduino_core\328P_16MHz Arduino\src\libArduinoCore.a succeeded
(C:\Users\Justin\workspaceArduino\arduino_core\328P_16MHz Arduino\src\libArduinoCore.a)wiring.c.o
(C:\Users\Justin\workspaceArduino\arduino_core\328P_16MHz Arduino\src\libArduinoCore.a)wiring_digital.c.o
(C:\Users\Justin\workspaceArduino\arduino_core\328P_16MHz Arduino\src\libArduinoCore.a)main.cpp.o
(C:\Users\Justin\workspaceArduino\arduino_core\328P_16MHz Arduino\src\libArduinoCore.a)new.cpp.o
(C:\Users\Justin\workspaceArduino\arduino_core\328P_16MHz Arduino\src\libArduinoCore.a)Print.cpp.o
(C:\Users\Justin\workspaceArduino\arduino_core\328P_16MHz Arduino\src\libArduinoCore.a)WString.cpp.o
attempt to open C:\Users\Justin\workspaceArduino\arduino_core\328P_16MHz Arduino/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open C:\Users\Justin\workspaceArduino\arduino_core\328P_16MHz Arduino\libgcc.a failed
attempt to open C:\Users\Justin\workspaceArduino\arduino_core\328P_16MHz Arduino\src/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open C:\Users\Justin\workspaceArduino\arduino_core\328P_16MHz Arduino\src\libgcc.a failed
attempt to open c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/avr5/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/avr5\libgcc.a succeeded
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/avr5\libgcc.a)_mulsi3.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/avr5\libgcc.a)_udivmodhi4.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/avr5\libgcc.a)_divmodhi4.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/avr5\libgcc.a)_udivmodsi4.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/avr5\libgcc.a)_exit.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/avr5\libgcc.a)_copy_data.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/avr5\libgcc.a)_clear_bss.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/avr5\libgcc.a)_ctors.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/avr5\libgcc.a)_dtors.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/avr5\libgcc.a)_fixunssfsi.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/avr5\libgcc.a)_addsub_sf.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/avr5\libgcc.a)_mul_sf.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/avr5\libgcc.a)_div_sf.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/avr5\libgcc.a)_gt_sf.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/avr5\libgcc.a)_ge_sf.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/avr5\libgcc.a)_lt_sf.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/avr5\libgcc.a)_si_to_sf.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/avr5\libgcc.a)_sf_to_si.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/avr5\libgcc.a)_thenan_sf.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/avr5\libgcc.a)_usi_to_sf.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/avr5\libgcc.a)_prologue.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/avr5\libgcc.a)_epilogue.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/avr5\libgcc.a)_tablejump.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/avr5\libgcc.a)_clzsi2.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/avr5\libgcc.a)_pack_sf.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/avr5\libgcc.a)_unpack_sf.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/avr5\libgcc.a)_fpcmp_parts_sf.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/avr5\libgcc.a)_clz.o
attempt to open C:\Users\Justin\workspaceArduino\arduino_core\328P_16MHz Arduino/libc.so failed
attempt to open C:\Users\Justin\workspaceArduino\arduino_core\328P_16MHz Arduino\libc.a failed
attempt to open C:\Users\Justin\workspaceArduino\arduino_core\328P_16MHz Arduino\src/libc.so failed
attempt to open C:\Users\Justin\workspaceArduino\arduino_core\328P_16MHz Arduino\src\libc.a failed
attempt to open c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/avr5/libc.so failed
attempt to open c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/avr5\libc.a failed
attempt to open c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/../../../../avr/lib/avr5/libc.so failed
attempt to open c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/../../../../avr/lib/avr5\libc.a succeeded
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/../../../../avr/lib/avr5\libc.a)malloc.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/../../../../avr/lib/avr5\libc.a)realloc.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/../../../../avr/lib/avr5\libc.a)atof.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/../../../../avr/lib/avr5\libc.a)atoi.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/../../../../avr/lib/avr5\libc.a)atol.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/../../../../avr/lib/avr5\libc.a)isspace.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/../../../../avr/lib/avr5\libc.a)tolower.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/../../../../avr/lib/avr5\libc.a)toupper.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/../../../../avr/lib/avr5\libc.a)memcpy.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/../../../../avr/lib/avr5\libc.a)memmove.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/../../../../avr/lib/avr5\libc.a)strchr.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/../../../../avr/lib/avr5\libc.a)strcmp.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/../../../../avr/lib/avr5\libc.a)strcpy.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/../../../../avr/lib/avr5\libc.a)strncmp.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/../../../../avr/lib/avr5\libc.a)strncpy.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/../../../../avr/lib/avr5\libc.a)strrchr.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/../../../../avr/lib/avr5\libc.a)strstr.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/../../../../avr/lib/avr5\libc.a)itoa.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/../../../../avr/lib/avr5\libc.a)ltoa.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/../../../../avr/lib/avr5\libc.a)mulsi10.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/../../../../avr/lib/avr5\libc.a)mul10.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/../../../../avr/lib/avr5\libc.a)ultoa.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/../../../../avr/lib/avr5\libc.a)utoa.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/../../../../avr/lib/avr5\libc.a)strtod.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/../../../../avr/lib/avr5\libc.a)cty_isfalse.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/../../../../avr/lib/avr5\libc.a)strncasecmp_P.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/../../../../avr/lib/avr5\libc.a)strrev.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/../../../../avr/lib/avr5\libc.a)cmpsf2.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/../../../../avr/lib/avr5\libc.a)fp_cmp.o
(c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/../../../../avr/lib/avr5\libc.a)errno.o
c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/../../../../avr/lib/avr5\libc.a(cmpsf2.o): In function `__lesf2':
attempt to open C:\Users\Justin\workspaceArduino\arduino_core\328P_16MHz Arduino/libgcc.so failed
(.text.fplib+0x0): multiple definition of `__ltsf2'
attempt to open C:\Users\Justin\workspaceArduino\arduino_core\328P_16MHz Arduino\libgcc.a failed
attempt to open C:\Users\Justin\workspaceArduino\arduino_core\328P_16MHz Arduino\src/libgcc.so failed
c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/avr5\libgcc.a(_lt_sf.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here
attempt to open C:\Users\Justin\workspaceArduino\arduino_core\328P_16MHz Arduino\src\libgcc.a failed
attempt to open c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/avr5/libgcc.so failed
attempt to open c:/users/justin/arduino/arduino-1.0/hardware/tools/avr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/4.3.2/avr5\libgcc.a succeeded
make: *** [CustomLEDPoi.elf] Error 1

**** Build Finished ****
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that I did not add the libary m. So I appended -lm using the add libraries option.
The make file now has this command.

```
 avr-g++ -o"CustomLEDPoi.elf"  ./src/glowstick2.o  ./lib/CShiftPWM.o ./lib/MeetAndroid.o ./lib/hsv2rgb.o  ./arduinolib/HardwareSerial.o ./arduinolib/SPI.o   -larduino_core -lm -Wl,-Map,CustomLEDPoi.map,--cref -Wl,--gc-sections -L"C:\Users\Justin\workspaceArduino\arduino_core\328P_16MHz Arduino" -L"C:\Users\Justin\workspaceArduino\arduino_core\328P_16MHz Arduino\src" -Xlinker -verbose -mmcu=atmega328p
```

This still gave me the same issue.
Looking at the guide at http://arduino.cc/playground/Code/Eclipse 
It says,

> If you're using C++ then the hex file can get really big. In the
>   linker menu, change the  command to avr-gcc and the command line
>   pattern to the following: ${COMMAND} --cref -s -Os
>   ${OUTPUT_FLAG}${OUTPUT_PREFIX}${OUTPUT} ${INPUTS} -lm ${FLAGS}

My make file now has this command.

```
avr-g++ --cref -s -Os -o"CustomLEDPoi.elf"  ./src/glowstick2.o  ./lib/CShiftPWM.o ./lib/MeetAndroid.o ./lib/hsv2rgb.o  ./arduinolib/HardwareSerial.o ./arduinolib/SPI.o   -larduino_core -lm -lm -Wl,-Map,CustomLEDPoi.map,--cref -Wl,--gc-sections -L"C:\Users\Justin\workspaceArduino\arduino_core\328P_16MHz Arduino" -L"C:\Users\Justin\workspaceArduino\arduino_core\328P_16MHz Arduino\src" -Xlinker -verbose -mmcu=atmega328p
```

Comment: Why does the 2 -lm fix the issue and not a single?

Answer (score 0):

here is catastrohic error for `ATmega32 (avr5)` in GCC linker script:
data      `(rw!x) : ORIGIN = 0x800060, LENGTH = 0xffa0`

the manual declares:

```
(0xC6) UDR0 USART I/O Data Register
```

the at address (0xC6) will be owerwritten by by user .data